# Which CIL contains which classes?

Tags: content-delivery, web8.5, java, api, cil

Is there any list which references which CIL contains which classes?

Official CD API documentation states which class is in which package, but not which class is in which `.jar` file.

This is really unpractical because if I want to import some class to my solution, I must check in which package it is, and then search through all `.jar` files for that package.

It was easy in 2013 since there were only few `.jar` files, but with the new architecture, there are significantly more, so searching is quite difficult and impractical.

Comment: Do you use Maven and cil from Maven Central? That should automatically solve it for you.

Comment: I would recommend referring to the installation media folder **SDL Web 8.5\SDL Web 8.5\Content Delivery\roles\api\rest\java\lib**, get all the jars and dependencies listed and required for CIL to work with web apps, same if you use XPM, UGC, XO, and ADF refer to the corresponding web-extensions and rest lib jars and config files and dependencies to work with, you can import all the sdl related jars to your local repository, third-party jars you can import from maven with corresponding versions then it will resolve your issues.

Comment: Actually @Velmurugan, this is exactly what i want to avoid. I thought that entire purpose of separating classes into numerous .jars was to use just ones you need, not all. This way I am back to square one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a list, but there is way (in Eclipse), which can help you determine where class is locating

1. Go to the `Navigate` menu,
2. `Open Type...` (or `Ctrl-Shift-T`),
3. Then type in the class name and see the list of possible jars where it could be coming from.

Hope it helps.

[image]